# Select link before active link in css

Tags: css

is there a way i can select the previous link from the active link in css?
i want to apply a specific style to the link previous from the active link e.g. link 3 is the active link so i want to style just link 2:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

i know i can easily do this in jquery, but i want to know if there is away that this can be achieved in css.

those links are inline with eachother to make a the navigation menu of the website

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector in CSS

Comment: How those links are shown? Are they placed in the same line left floated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its counter intuitive, but can be done.

You need to reverse your items and float them in the opposite direction, then use the next sibling adjacency selector.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/rjwg8/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    display:inline-block; /* <-- disguise the float:right position change */
}
li {
    float:right; /* <-- re-reverse item ordering in DOM */
    display:inline-block;
}
li.active + li a {
    color:pink; /* <-- select the next sibling (which due to reversing the DOM elements is now the previous one */
}
```

Comment: how do you know that his links are floated? there's nothing (yet) in the question to suppose so.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan...I know, the floating is part of the answer and only depends on the HTML in the question.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick... the '+' operator in the selector was new to me

Comment: The only concern is when the website is in a responsive mode, the solution will make link 1(home) displayed at the bottom, which is not the traditional way to have it!